# $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)g(x)dx=0 $ prove that $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \ni [a,b]$ (alternate methods)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis

Let $f:[a,b]\rightarrow R$ be a continuous function, and suppose that for every continuous function $g:[a,b]\rightarrow R$, we have that  $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)g(x)dx=0 $ prove that $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \ni [a,b]$

I know I can solve the problem using this method: Take $g = f$, then $g$ is continuous at $[a,b]$ and

$$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)g(x)dx = \int_{a}^{b}f^2(x)dx = 0$$

If $f$ is continuous for all $x \in [a,b]$, suppose for a moment that $f(x) \neq 0$ then $f^2(c) > 0$ for some $c \in [a,b]$. This would give

$$\int_{a}^{b}f^2(x)dx > 0$$

**HOWEVER**, I want to know if there is a way to solve this problem using integration by parts or the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality:
So I have something along the lines of:
Assuming $\int g(x)dx=G(x)$ and using integration by parts
$f(b)G(b)-f(a)G(a)-\int_{a}^{b}f'(x)G(x)dx = 0 $ then

$f(b)G(b)-f(a)G(a)=\int_{a}^{b}f'(x)G(x)dx $

**apply C-S inequality**

$(f(b)G(b)-f(a)G(a))^2=(\int_{a}^{b}f'(x)G(x)dx)^2\leq \int_{a}^{b}(f'(x))^2dx\int_{a}^{b}(G(x))^2dx$

continuing...
$(f(b)G(b))^2-2f(a)G(a)f(b)G(b)+(f(a)G(a))^2 \leq \int_{a}^{b}(f'(x))^2dx\int_{a}^{b}(G(x))^2dx$ and sort of lost here?

Comment: $f(x)g(x)\neq f^2(x)$. Is there a typo?

Answer (score 1):

Two comments:

1. The answer to your question is no, because you can't differentiate $f(x)$ if your only hypothesis is that $f$ is continuous. So your integration by parts makes no sense.
2. Your "proof" at the top isn't quite right. It's not enough to note that $f^2(c)>0$ for a single *point* $c$. You need to invoke continuity to deduce that $f^2(x)>0$ for all $x$ in a sufficiently small open *interval* around $c$.

Comment: What if we assume that $f(x)$ is, in fact, differentiable?